# Type guard two type of functions with same arguments but different return type

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I would like to check if the passed type is the right type. See code example below. But I don't know how to check based on the return type because the arguments of `FunctionA` and `FunctionB` are the same.

```
type TypeA = { a: string };
type TypeB = { a?: string, b: Record<string, any> };

type FunctionA = ( argA: string ) => TypeA | Promise<TypeA>;

type FunctionB = ( argA: string ) => TypeB | Promise<TypeB>;

function isFunctionB(target: FunctionA | FunctionB): target is FunctionB {
  return true //How do I check the type without running the function
}
 
class Test {

    myFunction?: FunctionA | FunctionB;
    mustBeFunctionB: boolean;

    constructor({
        myFunction,
        mustBeFunctionB
    }: {
        myFunction?:  FunctionA | FunctionB;
        mustBeFunctionB: boolean;
    }) {
        this.myFunction = myFunction;
        this.mustBeFunctionB = mustBeFunctionB

        if (mustBeFunctionB && myFunction && !isFunctionB(myFunction)) {
            throw new Error(
                "Invalid constructor arguments! myFunction must be a type of FunctionB"
            );
        } else {
            console.log("Passed")
        }
    }
}

async function myFunctionA(argA: string): Promise<{ a: string }> {
  return { a: "test" };
}

const test = new Test({
  myFunction: myFunctionA,
  mustBeFunctionB: true
}); // This should fail but it still passed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to check whether a function conforms to a given signature (including the return type) at runtime without executing it as the type information does not exist then.

The only way I can think of to solve this problem would be to use branded types, like so:

```js
type TypeA = { a: string };
type TypeB = { a?: string, b: Record<string, any> };

type FunctionA = (( argA: string ) => TypeA | Promise<TypeA>) & { __brand: 'A' };

type FunctionB = (( argA: string ) => TypeB | Promise<TypeB>) & { __brand: 'B' };

// ...

const myFunctionA: FunctionA = async (argA: string): Promise<{ a: string }> => {
  return { a: "test" };
}

myFunctionA.__brand = 'A'

// ...

function isFunctionB(target: FunctionA | FunctionB): target is FunctionB {
  return target.__brand === 'B';
}
```

This will allow you to difference both types at runtime, given they are defined properly.

You might want to look at [`ts-brand`](https://github.com/kourge/ts-brand) if you're planning on reusing this sort of pattern more often.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Method Overloading

You can make use of [method overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to achieve it.
Here is a simplified code sample to present the concept.

```
// if mustBeFunctionB is true, myFunction should be FunctionB
function fun(myFunction: FunctionB, mustBeFunctionB: true): any
// if mustBeFunctionB is false, myFunction could be FunctionA or FunctionB
function fun(myFunction: FunctionA | FunctionB, mustBeFunctionB: false): any
// the base type defination, should be compatible with all types above
function fun(myFunction: FunctionA | FunctionB, mustBeFunctionB: boolean): any {

};
```

It can also be used for class constructor. See the modification of your code in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8oEMBcUDOwATgJYB2A5lAL4DcAUKJLPAEIrpYD8uBJFANFABGuAEoQAxgHtCAEwA8vMuUGZSIAHzV6DeFABiAV1ITgxKaSSoAFFkLkEPIsqgBKFFriQkAHygAFQikAW2I8CHkvRA0dRmgjEzMLNhs7Byc+SndkT1YoP0CQsIiolhi6OgkAG0w8PFgIAnQKqFaoYJAE03NSbgNjbotffsSelno29sMCFggupNIWXCEpKSqINR1J6VJeQ1MZax2AM2JyXDQ6ScmO+Z7cO+SJ69bg6eBZx8XcIkMIZ9aVFcVzaOz2B0IRwsp3OzRer06AwWDyRPWGX3GIJebxmc1RyVwx0wVXCAOowO2FnBwEOl3h7URows-Cx1xxHzxTMWrKoF1ZN0Zg16uBGQvR+MWZJu70+EqWwlW602PPcdPhwAAFmEAHS3CXsPVcqVtTU69myrkpKa4jE8uhUCq1EAmKDHfWGsXWTD2Rz4ZwUVy4QqhcKReAILRqwgQYCGQikDg4KAAImAjWAye09sdeGdEld7sFCxYXp9GWUgYCQRDJVYkZB0dj8Y4InQVCzDropAgAHcGgRrGqPciGV8ECzXjLOUL5USSRB7a56N2+zB04OQcP7qO5RPrRyMYTieFF8ve-3gBuEV9cFuhnvzdPiz9CH9T13z2uB0Oi9u74sHynQ8oF+BcgRoIA)

---

Solution 2: Union type parameter

You can also declare the input with [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) to specify the peer of the `mustBeFunctionB` flag if you okay with a single object config as in your code.

```
constructor({
    myFunction,
    mustBeFunctionB
}: {
    myFunction: FunctionB;
    mustBeFunctionB: true;
} | {
    myFunction?:  FunctionA | FunctionB;
    mustBeFunctionB: false;
})
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8oEMBcUDOwATgJYB2A5lAL4DcAUKJLPAEIrpYD8uBJFANFABGuAEoQAxgHtCAEwA8vMuUGZSIAHzV6DeFABiAV1ITgxKaSSoAFFkLkEPIsqgBKFFriQkAHygAFQikAW2I8CHkvRA0dRmgjEzMLNhs7Byc%20SndkT1YoP0CQsIiolhi6OgkAG0w8PFgIAnQKqFaoYJAE03NSbgNjbotffsSelno29sMCFggupNIWXCEpKSqINR1J6VJeQ1MZazQ6ScmO%20Z7%20E9PW4OngWYvk69aqXGOb286BhdwnxYmnzuMzmPzGuCIhgggNe%20Wan3a31GFj6I0Gljh-3GL1OwIeoORi1wADNMFVwjDqO4Pp9gAALMIAOnOYIs7BZhMpk3pTLxj1Zi3Z935hJYOKodAldFqIBMUGJAsR-wQ1kw9kc%20GcFFcuEKoXCkXgCC0NMIEGAhkIpA4OCgACJgI1gHbtJKKjK5QrCUqBSxVeqMsodQEgvqSqwTdczRarRwROgqK6paQIAB3BoEI7XDno3A5hYIK63YUE9FLeVk8KS1z0FPpmBOrNff55pFlotTEFYkmViDV2tpjPAJs%20wmt5UdvmlhblyF9qg1uh1ocj-M9ce%20ycl7tQOf9oA)

---

Beware that these solutions does not check the exact context on runtime, but just a "type guard" as you stated in the title. However, typescript will prevent you from making wrong input, which is the concept of typescript.